# Please Help me to optimise mysql query containing subqueries for just a few hundred records

Tags: mysql, indexing

Table details-->

```
CREATE TABLE `redeem_vouchers` (
  `voucherid` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `voucheramount` decimal(18,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `redeemedto` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `redeemedon` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `transid` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `paymentconfirmed` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `confirmedby` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `confirmedon` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `redeemedby` int(11) DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`voucherid`),
  KEY `NewIndex2` (`redeemedto`),
  KEY `NewIndex3` (`voucheramount`),
  FULLTEXT KEY `NewIndex1` (`transid`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Query-->

```
SELECT DISTINCT(transid),
    (SELECT (COUNT(voucheramount)*16) FROM redeem_vouchers WHERE transid = r.transid) AS  amount,
    (SELECT redeemedto FROM redeem_vouchers WHERE transid = r.transid LIMIT 0,1) AS 'Name' 
FROM 
    redeem_vouchers r 
WHERE 
    confirmedon 
BETWEEN ('2013-07-23 19:00:00') AND ('2013-07-24 19:00:00')
```

Table contains just 4909 rows and query is taking 35 seconds to return result.
I have added 4 indexes but found no speed gain. I know I am doing something dangerous but I am new to sql. Please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would try this query, that uses GROUP BY:

```
SELECT
  transid,
  COUNT(voucheramount)*16 AS Amount,
  redeemedto As `Name`
FROM
  redeem_vouchers
WHERE
  confirmedon BETWEEN '2013-07-23 19:00:00' AND '2013-07-24 19:00:00'
GROUP BY
  transid
```

redeemedto is a non-aggregated column, and its value will be undetermined, but it is undetermined in your original query as well since you are using LIMIT to get the first record, but you are not using ORDER BY.

If all redeemedto values are the same, it will be fine - or you can use

```
MAX(redeemedto) As `Name`
```

to make the query SQL standard.

Comment: for a transaction all redeemed_to value is same as itis redeemed to only one person.